# Fedora 34 NVIDIA kernel module missing. Falling back to nouveau

Tags: linux, kernel, fedora, nvidia

Обновил систему с 32 до 34 (через 33) и никак не могу заставить работать нвидию. Получаю ошибку при загрузке. (В 33 была та же проблема.)

```
Fedora 34 NVIDIA kernel module missing. Falling back to nouveau
```

После установки драйверов делал

```
sudo akmods --force
sudo dracut -- force

#Даже вот что делал
sudo akmods-shotdown #нашел рекомендацию

#В последствии вот что, чтобы создать файл настроек
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

в общем, следовал этому [Правильная установка драйверов NVIDIA в Fedora](https://www.easycoding.org/2017/01/11/pravilnaya-ustanovka-drajverov-nvidia-v-fedora.html)

Ничего не помогает.

Видеокарта 650Ти жефорс (понимаю, что древняя). Драйвера "стандартные" не 390хх, хотя с ними такая же проблема. После установки 340хх получил подвисания при загрузке, которые чудом поборол и восстановил работоспособность системы

Думаю, фраза "Обновил систему" говорит сама за себя, что до обновления драйвер загружался.

Еще смущает то, что команда `sudo akmods --force` как будто ничего не делает, только выводит

```
]$ sudo akmods --force
Checking kmods exist for 5.12.13-300.fc34.x86_64           [  ОК  ]
```

По моему представлению, она должна собирать пакеты и не завершаться за секунду. Ещё: в 32 федоре, после обновления ядра, `sudo akmods --force` завершалась с ошибкой, поэтому и заходился с обновой

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло отключение (Secure Boot)  в настройках биоса . Потому что он не пускал драйвера видеокарты .
Вот тут случайно заметил что в этом может быть ошибка и это помогло

Comment: У меня эта опция была отключена, это самое первое, что я проверил. Это раз. И два система-то грузилась до обновления. Помог даунгрейд драйверов до 470хх и пересборка ядра